# afer eclipse update Features area is empty

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have installed features via install new software. I get the features in Installed Software but under Features tab, I have no features listed.

Comment: Which feature did you installed into what? Is there something in the error log? Could you give a step-by-step instruction how to reproduce your problem?

Comment: it is a custom RCP based on Luna 4.4, the log has no trace about an installation error. I updated to a new RCP version and then ı got no features listed in installation tab...

Comment: Please extend your question (instead of comments). I still don't understand what, which version you upgraded to and which _"installation tab"_  do you mean.